# Split controllers into 2 separate DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, assemblies, controllers

I have an idea I'd like to implement which basically involves separating the controllers in an MVC4 Project to 2 different projects. The reason being I'd like to be able to have different controllers for an internal admin section of my site and for the external client section. I'd like to make changes to each of them individually and add a new DLL to the website as I make changes...the changes to the internal admin section of the site thus not affecting the controllers DLL for the external client section for example.

Does anyone know if this is possible/advisable or of a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? So you have an area of the site, accessible by two controllers?

Comment: by adding a reference to another project in you'r solution you can achieve what you are looking for, in that referenced project add you'r controllers. it is totally doable ..

Comment: Hi Glitch...essentially I imagine I'd have the usual Website Project, a set of controllers in a different project for the internal admin section, and a set of controllers in another different project for the external client section of the site. I envisage that all the views will still remain in the Website project but I'm prepared to be corrected on this. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

taken from an [artical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx) :
"The MVC framework provides a default controller factory (aptly named DefaultControllerFactory) that will search through all the assemblies in an appdomain looking for all types that implement IController and whose name ends with "Controller." Thus, if you tell the factory to look for a "Home" controller, the factory can return a newly instantiated instance of a HomeController class regardless of the namespace or assembly it lives in—as long as it implements IController...."

by adding a reference to another project in you'r solution you can achieve what you are looking for, in that referenced project add you'r controllers. like written above the MVC Routing will find all controllers that been referenced in that solution.